# Align Imageview Just After Title Bar

Tags: android, android-layout, view

What im trying to do is align an ImageView (Linear Layout) just after the title bar of the activity.i tried using  `android:scaleType="fitStart`" this moved the imageview just a little bit up. Im a beginner i don't know how android will handle the placement of the image-view and other components in different screen sizes,i want the imageview to occupy the similar amount of space and the same aspect ratio and a fixed position irrespective of the device-screen or image sizes also other views(controls),How am i supposed to do that

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    android:orientation="vertical"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:layout_height="355dp"
        android:src="@drawable/jellyfish" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
        android:layout_width="262dp"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" 
        android:onClick="clickme"

        />



</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `android:gravity="center"` on your main `LinearLayout` which is essentially aligning all your child elements to both horizontal and vertical centers. What you should use is `android:gravity="center_horizontal"`.

As for the `ImageView` you might consider using `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` this will make sure the image is scaled to at least the size of your ImageView while maintaining aspect ratio, then cropped from the center.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks just worked,what about my second question will the image and controls take up the space in a similar fashion in different screensizes?

Comment: This has nothing to do with screen density, so the answer is yes d:) However you should consider supplying multiple versions of your image resource to all supported screen densities.